# modify existing post and include sample code

Tags: discussion

I have already posted a question here and got some great recommendations, yet I did not include code. I'm having some problems with implementing suggestions.  Is there a way to add comments and sample code to my existing question or do I need to ask a new question?  To add sample code do I simply copy from SDK and paste here?  This may seem trivial, but I can find no help on site anywhere with guidance here.  OK so now I see the menu items above this test box so that helps!  But I prefer to add to my existing question and not reinvent the wheel!

Comment: Maybe I should start over with new post.  Shame to lose excellent commentary from site experts in original.

Comment: This question really belongs on [meta], but yes, if a question has already received a bit of attention, you shouldn't modify it to ask something else.

Comment: Point taken!  Given that I am old school (think FORTRAN on punch cards),the enormous scope of Java is a bit intimidating.  I'm self taught and believe this is the way to go. Can't imagine a Java course for entry-level programming! This site is a great resource, although reading some of the convoluted code you see here is not for the faint of heart.  You guys that can spend a few minutes analyzing this code and identify problems are true experts and I'm glad I have you as a resource. Can't thank you enough!

Answer (score -1):

Best to start over and include some code.  Not much help here on this site.  I did find easy solution to posting code.  Seems copy/paste from SDK kept giving me silly formatting errors and would not post.  Ctrl-K was like ctrl-kluck that I could see.  So I used Word. I copied my code to Word and turned off grammar and spell check for document (also minimize margins). Pasted this to my comments here and rt-clicked to turn off pesky spell checker option. Not sure where people get the pretty colored text in their posts.  Maybe someday I'll learn this trick.  Hey newbies can do it.  Can't be that hard!